# Truncate all tables with flyway

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway, truncate

i'm new to flyway and i don't Know if it ils possible to use flyway to truncate all tables in specific schema, so i want to delete all data in this tables but don't want to delete tables.
When i use flyway.clean() it deletes all tables in this schema and i don't want that. Thank you guys

Comment: see this [issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/225) on github/flyway  (P.S. I do not know Flyway, but I know how to search the internet...)

Comment: Hi luuk i've Seen this issue on github, it was Closed without solution. Thank you.

Comment: Why not delete the tables?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in comments, Flyway doesn't currently have a built-in way to truncate data out of tables in the target database while leaving the schema in place.

There are ways that you could make this work using Flyway, however.

For instance, you could:

- Write or adapt a script that truncates all the tables in your database - for simplicity in ordering and execution, I would write this as a [repeatable migration](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#repeatable-migrations)
- Store this in its own migrations folder
- Specify that location when calling [flyway migrate](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/commandline/migrate) when you want to remove all the data

One thing to consider is that the script you use to truncate tables will often need to have logic specific to the database platform. Things like foreign keys, indexed views, etc, may cause truncate or delete commands to fail or to be very slow if commands are not run in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

> When i use flyway.clean() it deletes all tables

Yes. And you should have in your earliest scripts the commands to create those tables. So do a `clean`, and run all your scripts all over again.